# Postgres query with uppercase letters in Column name

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I searched and followed various online guide however am not successful with the following query, which while doesnt give errors, it does not get the expected results.

```
table gBInfo:
(columns) id,userId, fromGB, fromGBId      

table User:
(columns) id, firstName, lastName
```

query:

```
select "id", "firstName", "fromGB" 
from "User" join "gBInfo"
on 'User.id' = 'gBInfo.userId';
```

What do I get this query to work, with uppercase letters in column and table names.

Comment: You should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes are for string constants, not for identifiers. And each part of a multi-part identifier needs to be quoted separately:

```
select "id", "firstName", "fromGB" 
from "User" 
  join "gBInfo" on "User".id = "gBInfo"."userId";
```

The condition `'User.id' = 'gBInfo.userId'` simply compares the string value `User.id` with the string value `gBInfo.userId` which are obviously never equal.